# ttl not expired in JWT Auth Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, token, jwt

```
'ttl' => null,
'refresh_ttl' => null,
```

I need the token does not expire.. 
It does not work, it always returns "error": "token expired"

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question seems a little vague. What are you trying to accomplish? What behavior did you expect? What did you tried?

Comment: Have you tried setting them to `0`?

Comment: hi, I need the token does not expire

Comment: This functionality is not possible. Either provide very long time ie. 30 * 60 * 60 or use refresh token.sadly that will expire also.

Comment: @Sameer Shaikh: why is it not possible? Nothing prevent us from creating a very long lifetime JWT or a JWT that does not expire.

Answer (score 6):

In the file vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/config/config.php change the line

```
'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 60),
```

by the

```
'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', null),
```

Also remove `exp` in this line

```
 'required_claims' => [
        'iss',
        'iat',
        'exp',
        'nbf',
        'sub',
        'jti',
    ],
```

Works for my

Comment: You should not change anything in vendor dir

Answer (score 1):

Steps for not expiring login in JWTAuth:

1. Open `jwt.php` in config folder (if it not available then publish the `jwt.php` file using this command in project==>

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuthProviders\JWTAuthServiceProvider" )`

2. Change

`'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 60),`
to

`'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', null),`

3. remove exp in this line:-

`'required_claims' => [ 'iss', 'iat', 'exp', 'nbf', 'sub', 'jti', ],`

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite vague as we don't know which library/component is used to generate the Jot so we cannot know the way expiration claims are managed.
In general, to get a Jot that does not expire, such claims (`exp`, `ttl` or `refresh_ttl`) should not be part of the payload.

The following token will expire in 3600 sec.

```
{
    'iss': 'my-service'
    'aud': 'your-service'
    'sub': 'my-client'
    'ttl': 3600
}
```

The following token should never expire.

```
{
    'iss': 'my-service'
    'aud': 'your-service'
    'sub': 'my-client'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to expire the token conditionally.

1. Remove exp from required claims in config/jwt.php
2. Add this code snippet to set TTL to null within the controller.

```
if ( // your condition ) {
    $this->guard()->setTTL(null);
}
```